# Start a process and keep it running after the ruby script exits

Tags: ruby, linux, process, fork

I'm trying to write a ruby script that:

1. Run a command/script
2. Stores the command's process pid in a file so I can check if it's still running later, and
3. the command should keep running after the ruby code exits.

I'm successful in steps 1 and 2, but it looks like the started script (i.e, the child process) terminates once the ruby code is finished.

This is the last version of what I could think about (super simplified):

```
pid = fork do
  exec "/my/fancy/daemon/style/script"
end
File.open('tmp/process.pid', 'w') { |file| file.write(pid.to_s) }
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong? The ultimate goal is to keep the other script (i.e, the child process) running after the ruby code exits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "detach" your child process:

```
Process.detach(pid)
```

See [Process#detach](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Process.html#method-c-detach) for more info.

If you're running your script on a shell, and if your script is the last interactive process, your virtual terminal may exit and cause your child process to hangup as well. If you consider not sending output to the terminal, you can use Process.daemon before running exec.

See [Process#daemon](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Process.html#method-c-daemon).

Comment: I didn't quiet understand the `daemon` case, but `detach` worked just fine. The case is that the other script (which should keep running) is actually daemon-like and I don't care about it's output at all. Also, the ruby script is called using a cronjob (with [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever)) so it's not run from a terminal. Given these facts, do you advice to use `daemon` instead of `detach`?

Comment: @TamerShlash With those conditions I believe using `daemon` would be good but I'm not sure if `detach` is not necessary. It think it won't be bad to do both but just try. P.S. I believe you call it within the child's process and it's before doing `exec`.

Comment: I did as you said. But for some reason, using `daemon` will run the script but with a process pid different from the one returned by the `fork` block. Therefore I will just stick with `detach` as it works fine, thanks very much! :)